# Calculate transaction per ID by date

Tags: r

How to count the total number of transaction by id and by date ?

Sample data :

```
f<- data.frame(
id=c("A","A","A","A","C","C","D","D","E"),
start_date=c("6/3/2012","7/3/2012","7/3/2012","8/3/2012","5/3/2012","6/3/2012","6/3/2012","6/3/2012","5  /3/2012")

)
```

Excepted Output:

```
id | count
 A |  3     
 C |  2
 D |  1
 E |  1
```

Logic :

As A is 6 MARCH , 7 MARCH  AND 8 MARCH SO COUNT 3

C is 5 MARCH , 6 MARCH SO COUNT 2

so on...

I Tried with the following code , and I think it only count the number of the ID occurred in the data.

```
library(lubridate)
f$date <- mdy(f$Date)
f1 <- s[order(f$id, f$Date), ]
```

How can I implement this code to get my desire outcome?

[Note: The actual data is in huge volume, so optimization need to be consider.]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try. `f[!duplicated(f), ]` removes duplicates from `f` and then `aggregate` does the aggregation using `length` function i.e. gives count of `start_date` for each `id`

```
aggregate(start_date ~ id, f[!duplicated(f), ], length)
##   id start_date
## 1  A          3
## 2  C          2
## 3  D          1
## 4  E          1
```

Comment: Why remove duplicates? Aren't they all transactions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a different answer:

```
with(f, tapply(start_date, id, length))
A C D E 
4 2 2 1
```

Comment: heh, heh.  I _thought_ I was answering _this_ question.

Comment: If you're getting a different answer, isn't that an inherent question? Also, it's an **Excepted** output, so ... yeah... +1 and let me back away slowly. Of course, what if one "A" is omitted by `date`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what format you want the results in, but

```
rowSums(with(f, table(id, start_date)>0))
```

will return a named vector with the count of distinct days for each ID.

Comment: @momoni I'm glad you found something that worked. I see I read your question incorrectly the first time and have updated with an alternative solution.